# How to make use of the getChildren() and getParent() functions if they always return null?

Tags: entity, parent, children, shopware, shopware6

I've noticed entities can implement a getParent and getChildren function like the `ProductEntity`. It always seems to return `null` when I try to use either of them, even when trying to add `->addAssociation('parent')` or `->addAssociation('children')`. How do i load both the children and the parent using the criteria object?

Comment: You have to add the parent or children association just like you did. getChildren() returns entities only if you use it on a parent entity with children, e.g. main product with variants. getParent() works only for child entities, e.g. a variation of a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter for `children` will return `null` if a product simply has no children a.k.a. variants. Adding the associations should generally work. To test this you can try adding a filter to retrieve only results that should include children.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addAssociation('children');
$criteria->addFilter(new RangeFilter('childCount', [RangeFilter::GT => 0]));

/** @var ProductCollection $products */
$products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities();
var_dump($products->first()->getChildren());
```

The `parent` association however is different. If you try adding it, the data abstraction layer should throw a `ParentAssociationCanNotBeFetched` exception:

```
It is not possible to read the parent association directly. Please read the parents via a separate call over the repository
```

You will have to resolve the parents programmatically and set them to their respective children, if you want to work with the getter later on in the stack.

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new NotFilter(NotFilter::CONNECTION_AND, [new EqualsFilter('parentId', null)]));

/** @var ProductCollection $products */
$products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->getEntities();

$criteria = new Criteria($products->getParentIds());

/** @var ProductCollection $parents */
$parents = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, Context::createDefaultContext())->getEntities();

/** @var ProductEntity $product */
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $parent = $parents->get($product->getParentId());
    if (!$parent) {
        continue;
    }

    $product->setParent($parent);
}

var_dump($products->first()->getParent());
```

Comment: This boggles my mind and annoys me to no end. I've seen your answer in another thread where you proposed writing a raw query for gathering parent product number. The DAL makes it pretty obvious that you should simply get away with this using one line: `$criteria->addAssociation('parent');` however this is not possible. Why would this explicitly not be allowed?

Comment: Well, opinions may differ at this point. Some people would argue that self-joins are an anti-pattern and the ability to fetch even the children is a concession. In case of products people should be further disencouraged to fetch the parent, as it is not a purchasable good and only exists as a means for the variants, the actual pruchasable goods, to share inherited data from. So if you need data from the parent, you should consider using inheritable fields instead and leaving them empty on the variants, so their value may be inherited. That's a general architectural decision.